# IE9 and 10 doesn't reflect javascript cursor change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, binding, keyboard, cursor

The following code sample adds a semi transparent 100% overlay when a button is clicked. The overlay remains until the mouse button is released. Here's what is supposed to happen:

- Click on the button and hold the mouse down.
- While the mouse is down press and release the shift key.
- When it's pressed, a div area
  indicates this with the text "horizontal" and the cursor changes to
  e-resize. When shift is released, the div indicates "vertical" and
  the cursor changes to n-resize.

In IE9/10, the text changes but the cursor remains the same. I've tried changing the key bind to the body level and to the overlay level but to no avail.

Here's the code: (I tried putting it into jsfiddle and jsbin but for some reason they ignore the key presses completely).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        .overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: fixed;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        .vertical { cursor: n-resize !important; }
        .horizontal { cursor: e-resize !important; }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#button1").mousedown(onButtonMouseDown);

            function onButtonMouseDown(e) {

                var overlay;

                overlay = $("body").after("<div class=\"overlay\"></div>").next();
                overlay.addClass((e.shiftKey) ? "horizontal" : "vertical");

                $(document).bind("keydown.ntextbox", function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 16) {
                        overlay.removeClass("vertical").addClass("horizontal");
                        $("#div1").html("horizontal");
                    }
                });

                $(document).bind("keyup.ntextbox", function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 16) {
                        overlay.removeClass("horizontal").addClass("vertical");
                        $("#div1").html("vertical");
                    }
                });

                overlay.mouseup(function (e) {
                    overlay.remove();
                    $(document).unbind(".ntextbox");
                    return false;
                });

                return false;
            }

        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">...</div>
    <button id="button1">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following jQuery statements seems to fix it.

```
$(".overlay").css("cursor", "e-resize");
$(".overlay").css("cursor", "n-resize");
```

So, maybe something like this?

```
  $(document).bind("keydown.ntextbox", function (e) {
       if (e.which === 16) {
           overlay.removeClass("vertical").addClass("horizontal").css("cursor", "e-resize");
           $("#div1").html("horizontal");
       }
  });

  $(document).bind("keyup.ntextbox", function (e) {
       if (e.which === 16) {
           overlay.removeClass("horizontal").addClass("vertical").css("cursor", "n-resize");
           $("#div1").html("vertical");
       } 
  });
```

Comment: That's crazy. I had tried it by setting just the style with the .css method but that didn't work. As you say, I have to set both the class and the style!

Answer (score 2):

This was a rather odd problem to nail down, but I've targeted the main issue. Rather than duplicating your logic, adding cursors a second time after already having set the appropriate styles, you can instead replace the button with a clone of itself. Let me explain.

When you `mousedown` on the button this takes control of the cursor, no longer permitting you to modify it in IE. After about an hour of trying *this* and *that*, I finally realized that if you call `$(this).remove()` on the button event, the UI is no longer blocked, and you can freely update the cursor as you wish. This does, however, leave us without a button.

In the end if modified the button logic to replace itself with a clone. This effectively does away with the button that is blocking the cursor-change, though the end-user knows that no such switch has taken place.

Additionally, I updated some of your code since it had a few very serious issues (such as adding the overlay element outside of the body tag, and more).

The following could be cleaned up a bit:

```
var overlay = $("<div>", {
    'class':'overlay', 
    'mouseup':function(){ $(this).hide() } 
}).hide().appendTo("body");;

$("#button1").on("mousedown", function(){
    overlay.show();
    // Replacing this button permits the cursor
    // to be updated in IE
    $(this).replaceWith( $(this).clone(true) );
});

$(document).on('keydown keyup', function(e){
    if ( e.which === 16 && overlay.is(":visible") ) {
        if ( e.type === "keyup" ) {
            overlay.addClass("vertical").removeClass("horizontal");
        } else {
            overlay.addClass("horizontal").removeClass("vertical");
        }
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/p6eZw/

It's worth noting that Chrome still blocks the user's ability to change the cursor, according to my tests. I've not looked at Firefox, Safari or Opera.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look at this. I've tried your jsfiddle but for me it only works in FF; other tests were IE9, IE10, Chrome and Opera. Also, you say there were a few serious issues apart from the (embarrassing) body issue. Could you let me know what they were. Cheers.

Comment: @Jules It works in IE10 and IE9 as well, but you have to be moving the mouse around while tapping on the shift key. The cursor will only update while the mouse is moving: don't ask me why, I haven't the slightest clue :) The other issues were things like re-creating the overlay element every time you press the button, and destroying it every time you release the mouse. Additionally, you were binding and unbinding on every button-press cycle as well. All of this puts unnecessary performance costs at risk.